# Can't override node settings in ES integration test

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am writing an integration test for elasticsearch 5.3.

```
public class ProtectedWordsIndexTests extends ESIntegTestCase {
  private final WordDelimiterActionListener wordsListener = 
  WordDelimiterActionListener.getInstance();
  private final static String INDEX_NAME = "protected_words";
  private final static String TYPE_NAME = "word";
  private final static String FILTER_NAME = "my_word_delimiter";

  @Override
  protected Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> nodePlugins() {
     return Collections.singleton(WordDelimiterPlugin.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected Settings nodeSettings(int nodeOrdinal) {
    return builder()
       .put("plugin.types", TYPE_NAME)
       .put("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.refresh_interval", "500ms")
       .put(super.nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal))
       .build();
  }

  public void testAddWordToIndex() throws Exception {
     Settings indexSettings = builder()
       .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_VERSION_CREATED, Version.CURRENT)
       .put("index.analysis.filter.my_word_delimiter.type", "dynamic_word_delimiter")
       .build();
     TokenFilterFactory filterFactory = filterFactory(indexSettings, FILTER_NAME);

     createIndex(INDEX_NAME);
     ensureGreen();
     client().prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, TYPE_NAME, "1")
        .setSource("word", "1tb")
        .execute();

     Thread.sleep(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(1).getMillis());

     Set<String> protectedWords = wordsListener.getProtectedWords();
     assertTrue(protectedWords.size() == 1);
  }
}
```

When I am running testAddWordToIndex() I am getting the following error:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting
>   [plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.refresh_interval] please check that any
>   required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
>   documentation for removed settings"

If I remove the following part and increase the refresh interval to be more than the default, the test passes. So I just can't override this.

> .put("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.refresh_interval", "500ms")

The default refresh interval is declared here:

```
public class WordDelimiterRunnable extends AbstractRunnable {
   public static final TimeValue REFRESH_INTERVAL = TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(20);
   public static final String INDEX_NAME = "protected_words";
   public static final String INDEX_TYPE = "word";
   public static final int RESULTS_SIZE = 10000;

   private volatile boolean running;
   private final Client client;
   private final String index;
   private final long interval;
   private final String type;

   public WordDelimiterRunnable(Client client, Settings settings) {
     this.client = client;
     this.index = settings.get("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.protected_words_index", INDEX_NAME);
     this.type = settings.get("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.protected_words_type", INDEX_TYPE);
     this.interval = settings.getAsTime("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.refresh_interval", REFRESH_INTERVAL).getMillis();
   }
   // more code here
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, hence the comment, but maybe it has to do with the order of the put()? I would try doing ` return builder().put(super.nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal)).put("plugin.types", TYPE_NAME).put("plugin.dynamic_word_delimiter.refresh_interval", "500ms").build();` if you haven't already

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Thought about this and tried it, didn't work.

Comment: `.put("plugin.types", TYPE_NAME)` usually takes the class name of the plugin. From the exception it says that the plugin is not loaded. If you have the class name of the plugin you can try that

Comment: Tried that as well, nothing changes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the setting using the SettingsModule#registerSettings(Setting) method as explain here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#breaking_50_settings_changes